# Long run .NET Core API getting slower

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, scheduler

I am running a scheduler task every day. The scheduler calls an API endpoint that calculates the user's income and adds a commission on his purchases. There are around 50K-100K insert operations after checking their current income status.

The problem is it getting slower. The first 10K is inserted within 10 minutes after that it is taking more time for each operation. I can see for 50K purchases it is taking around 2 hours. After certain operations, the time increases almost exponentially and these get slower and slower.

How can I make faster the operations?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried processing asynchronously, like in [this example](https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore)? I'm guessing it might have something to do with your webserver.

Comment: @Chen yes, all the operations are asynchronous for this endpoint. But I didn't try background service. Not sure the background service will make the operation faster.